# How to replace Ionic core with ReactNative or Flutter?

Tags: flutter, react-native, ionic-framework

I want to migrate my core app from ionic to RNative or Flutter and push a new version of the app into the app and play store.

That means keeping my keys for deployments.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You cant, you need to create a whole no project in react or flutter and move the code from ionic project into that new project and it wont be a copy and paste since those are different frameworks and require different syntaxes.